# Kivy doesn't display Label

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

I have been making a simple sudoku program, and wanted to display numbers on each block, but this function just doesn't display anything
'''

```
def update_numbers(self):
    self.v_x, self.v_y = 90, 1190
    for row in board:
            for col in row:
            Label(text=str(col), pos=(self.v_x, self.v_y), size_hint=(0.08, 0.08))
        
        self.v_x += 60
    self.v_y += 60
```

'''

I also tried just displaying label without loop, but it failed too.

Comment: You are creating `Labels`, but you are not doing anything with them. You need to use an `add_widget()` method to add the `Labels` to some container/layout.

Comment: Well that fixed it :/... Thanks.